# How to close the tikz group plot inserted in a box and minipage environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, textwidth

Dear all I'm trying to insert a tikz picture (a group plot) in a box with a minipage environment but the node called mybox is not ended or closed properly. I tried to set the textwidth parameter and the minipage size but it doesn't work.

I include a picture of the result and the full code to reproduce it below

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

\title{STAT 251 Formula Sheet}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\advance\topmargin-.8in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.45in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.45in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,fillbetween}
\DeclareMathOperator{\CDF}{cdf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PDF}{pdf}

 \begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\huge{\textbf{STATS Cheatsheet\hfill {\large{\copyright}}}}}\\
\end{center}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries]

 %------------ Measures of Center ---------------
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [mybox] (box){%
 \begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}

 \begin{tabular}{lp{8cm} l}
    Media: 
    & $\overline{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n} = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n}{n} $ \\
    Mediana: & Si $n$ es par: $ \tilde{x} = \frac{(\frac{n}{2})^\text{th} \text{ obs.} + (\frac{n+1}{2})^\text{th} \text{ obs.}}{2} $ \\
            & Si $n$ es impar: $ \tilde{x} = \frac{n+1}{2}^\text{th}\text{ obs.}$ \\
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
};
%------------ Measures of Center Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Medidas de Centralizaci\'on};
\end{tikzpicture}


 %------------ Measures of Variability ---------------
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [mybox] (box){%
 \begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{lp{8cm} l}
    Rango: & $R = x_\text{mayor valor} - x_\text{menor valor}$\\
    Varianza: & $s^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})^2}{n-1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - n\overline{x}^2}{n-1}$\\
    Desviaci\'on T\'ipica: & $s = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})^2}{n-1}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - n\overline{x}^2}{n-1}}$\\
    IQR {\scriptsize{(interv. inter-cuart\'ilico)}:} & $\text{IQR} = \text{Q3} - \text{Q1}$
\end{tabular}\\

\textbf{C\'alculo de $\text{Q}_{(p)}$:}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item Sort data from smallest to largest: $x_{(1)} \leq x_{(2)} \leq ... \leq x_{(n)}$
    \item Compute the number $np + 0.5$
    \item If $np + 0.5$ is an integer, $m$, then: $\text{Q}_{(p)} = x_{(m)}$
    \item If $np + 0.5$ is not an integer, $m < np + 0.5 < m+1$ for some integer $m$, then:\\ $\text{Q}_{(p)} = \frac{x_{(m)}+x_{(m+1)}}{2}$
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Valores anormales ('outliers'):}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item Values smaller than $\text{Q1} - (1.5 \times \text{IQR})$ are outliers
    \item Values greater than $\text{Q3} + (1.5 \times \text{IQR})$ are outliers
\end{itemize}

\end{minipage}
 };
  %------------ Measures of Variability Header ---------------------
  \node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Medidas de Dispersi\'on};
   \end{tikzpicture}


  %------------ Discrete Random Variable and Distributions ---------------
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [mybox] (box){%
 \begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}
 Consider a \textbf{discrete} random variable $X$ \\

 \textbf{Probability Mass Function} (pmf): $f(x) = P(X = x)$
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ in $X$
    \item $\sum_x f(x) = 1$
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Cumulative Distributive Function} (cdf): $F(x) = P(X \leq x) = \sum_{k \leq x}f(k)$ \\

\begin{tabular}{lp{8cm} l}
    Mean ($\mu$): & $E(X) = \sum_{x}xf(x)$ \\
    Expected value: & $E(g(X)) = \sum_{x}g(x)f(x)$ \\
    Variance ($\sigma^2$): & $Var(X) = \sum_x (x-\mu)^2f(x) = E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$\\
    SD ($\sigma$): & $SD(X) = \sqrt{Var(X)}$
\end{tabular} \\
\\


\end{minipage}
 };
 %------------ Discrete Random Variable and Distributions Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Discrete Random Variables};
 \end{tikzpicture}


 %------------ Sets and Probability ---------------
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}

\textbf{Properties of Probability:}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item \textit{General Addition Rule:} $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$
    \item \textit{Complement Rule:} $P(A^c) = 1 - P(A)$
    \item If $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A \cap B) = P(A)$
    \item If $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A) \leq P(B)$
    \item $P(\emptyset) = 0$ and $P(S) = 1$
    \item $0 \leq P(A) \leq 1$ for all $A$
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Conditional Probability:}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ and $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$
    \item \textit{Multiplication Rule:} $P(A \cap B) = P(B) \times P(A|B)$ and \\ $P(A \cap 
 B) = P(A) \times P(B|A)$
    \item Events $A$ and $B$ are \textbf{independent} if and only if $P(A \cap B) = 
  P(A)P(B)$ \\ and thus $P(A|B) = P(A)$ and $P(B|A) = P(B)$
\end{itemize}

\begin{tabular}{l l l}
    \textbf{Bayes' Theorem:} 
    & $P(A_i|B)$ &$= \frac{P(B|A_i)P(A_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)P(B|A_i)}$\\
    && $= \frac{P(B|A_i)P(A_i)}{P(B|A_1)P(A_1) + P(B|A_2)P(A_2)+ . . . + P(B|A_n)P(A_n)}$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
 };
 %------------ Sets and Probability Header ---------------------
 \node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Sets and Probability};
 \end{tikzpicture}


 %------------ Continuous Random Variable and Distributions ---------------
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [mybox] (box){%
 \begin{minipage}{0.28\textwidth} %0.46
 Sea $X$ una variable aleatoria \textbf{continua} \\

  \textbf{Funci\'on de Densidad} (pdf):\\ $P(a \leq X \leq b) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$
   \begin{enumerate}
   \setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$
    \item $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x) dx = 1$
  \end{enumerate}

  \textbf{Cumulative Distributive Function} (cdf):\\ $F(x) = P(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) dt$ \\

  \begin{tabular}{lp{8cm} l}
    Mediana: & $x$ tal que $F(x) = 0.5$ \\
    $Q_1$ y $Q_3$: & $x$ tal que $F(x) = 0.25$\\
     & y $x$ tal que $F(x) = 0.75$\\
    Media ($\mu$): & $E(X) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} xf(x) dx$ \\
    Valor esperado: & $E(g(X)) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} g(x)f(x) dx$ \\
    Varianza ($\sigma^2$): & $Var(X) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (x-\mu)^2f(x) dx$\\
& \qquad\qquad$ = E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$\\
    D. T\'ipica ($\sigma$): & $DT(X) = \sqrt{Var(X)}$
\end{tabular} 
\end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{0.38\textwidth}
 \vspace{-0.75cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=0.77, transform canvas={scale=0.77}, declare function={%
    normcdf(\x,\m,\s)=1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\m)/\s)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\m)/\s));
    gauss(\x,\u,\v)=1/(\v*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\u)^2)/(2*\v^2));
   }]
 \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2},
   xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=0,
   domain=-3:3,xlabel=$x$,axis lines=middle,axis on top]
   \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$\PDF(x)$,ytick=\empty,ymax=0.6]
  \addplot[smooth, black,thick,name path=gauss] {gauss(x,0,1)};     
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$\CDF(x)$,ymax=1.19]
  \addplot[smooth, black,thick] {normcdf(x,0,1)};
 
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
};
 %------------ Continuous Random Variable and Distributions Header ---------------------
  \node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Continuous Random Variables};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: `\end{multicols*}` is missing from the end of your example. Also, nested `tikzpicture` environments are not officially supported... not to mention nesting `tikzpicture` in a `minipage` which is nested in another `tikzpicture`. Have a look at `tcolorbox` package, especially the examples given in its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), sec. _10.2.2_ Options for the Boxed Title Placement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from adding `\end{multicols*}` just before `\end{document}`, changing the beginning of last `minipage` from `\begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}` to `\begin{minipage}{0.38\textwidth}` solves your problem.

To make the two framed rectangles share the same width, add `%` after the last two `\end{minipage}`.

Continued from [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575694/how-to-close-the-tikz-group-plot-inserted-in-a-box-and-minipage-environment#comment1449691_575694), I sincerely recommend you to have a look at `tcolorbox` package.

---

A `tcolorbox` example. Here `tcolorbox` environments are used only, you may find `magazine` and `poster` libraries of this package useful as well.

```tex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{pst-func}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

\title{STAT 251 Formula Sheet}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\advance\topmargin-.8in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.45in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.45in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,fillbetween}
\DeclareMathOperator{\CDF}{cdf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PDF}{pdf}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

 \begin{document}


{\huge{\textbf{STATS Cheatsheet\hfill {\large{\copyright}}}}}

%\begin{multicols*}{2}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries]

\tcbset{
  my tcb box/.style={
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=4mm,yshift=-3mm},
    boxed title style={colback=black,sharp corners},
    colback=white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=4mm
  }
}


\begin{tcolorbox}[my tcb box, title=Medidas de Centralizaci\'on]
  \begin{tabular}{lp{8cm} l}
    Media:   & $\overline{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n} = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n}{n} $                                        &  \\
    Mediana: & Si $n$ es par: $ \tilde{x} = \frac{(\frac{n}{2})^\text{th} \text{ obs.} + (\frac{n+1}{2})^\text{th} \text{ obs.}}{2} $ &  \\
             & Si $n$ es impar: $ \tilde{x} = \frac{n+1}{2}^\text{th}\text{ obs.}$                                                    &
  \end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[my tcb box, title=Medidas de Dispersi\'on]
  \begin{tabular}{lp{8cm} l}
      Rango: & $R = x_\text{mayor valor} - x_\text{menor valor}$\\
      Varianza: & $s^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})^2}{n-1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - n\overline{x}^2}{n-1}$\\
      Desviaci\'on T\'ipica: & $s = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})^2}{n-1}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - n\overline{x}^2}{n-1}}$\\
      IQR {\scriptsize{(interv. inter-cuart\'ilico)}:} & $\text{IQR} = \text{Q3} - \text{Q1}$
  \end{tabular}\\
  
  \textbf{C\'alculo de $\text{Q}_{(p)}$:}
  \begin{itemize}
  \setlength\itemsep{0em}
      \item Sort data from smallest to largest: $x_{(1)} \leq x_{(2)} \leq ... \leq x_{(n)}$
      \item Compute the number $np + 0.5$
      \item If $np + 0.5$ is an integer, $m$, then: $\text{Q}_{(p)} = x_{(m)}$
      \item If $np + 0.5$ is not an integer, $m < np + 0.5 < m+1$ for some integer $m$, then:\\ $\text{Q}_{(p)} = \frac{x_{(m)}+x_{(m+1)}}{2}$
  \end{itemize}
  
  \textbf{Valores anormales ('outliers'):}
  \begin{itemize}
  \setlength\itemsep{0em}
      \item Values smaller than $\text{Q1} - (1.5 \times \text{IQR})$ are outliers
      \item Values greater than $\text{Q3} + (1.5 \times \text{IQR})$ are outliers
  \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[my tcb box, title=Discrete Random Variables]
   Consider a \textbf{discrete} random variable $X$ \\
  
   \textbf{Probability Mass Function} (pmf): $f(x) = P(X = x)$
  \begin{enumerate}
  \setlength\itemsep{0em}
      \item $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ in $X$
      \item $\sum_x f(x) = 1$
  \end{enumerate}
  
  \textbf{Cumulative Distributive Function} (cdf): $F(x) = P(X \leq x) = \sum_{k \leq x}f(k)$ \\
  
  \begin{tabular}{lp{8cm} l}
    Mean ($\mu$):          & $E(X) = \sum_{x}xf(x)$                            &  \\
    Expected value:        & $E(g(X)) = \sum_{x}g(x)f(x)$                      &  \\
    Variance ($\sigma^2$): & $Var(X) = \sum_x (x-\mu)^2f(x) = E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$ &  \\
    SD ($\sigma$):         & $SD(X) = \sqrt{Var(X)}$                           &
  \end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}

\newpage

\begin{tcolorbox}[my tcb box, title=Sets and Probability]
  \textbf{Properties of Probability:}
  \begin{itemize}
  \setlength\itemsep{0em}
      \item \textit{General Addition Rule:} $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$
      \item \textit{Complement Rule:} $P(A^c) = 1 - P(A)$
      \item If $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A \cap B) = P(A)$
      \item If $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A) \leq P(B)$
      \item $P(\emptyset) = 0$ and $P(S) = 1$
      \item $0 \leq P(A) \leq 1$ for all $A$
  \end{itemize}
  
  \textbf{Conditional Probability:}
  \begin{itemize}
  \setlength\itemsep{0em}
      \item $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ and $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$
      \item \textit{Multiplication Rule:} $P(A \cap B) = P(B) \times P(A|B)$ and \\ $P(A \cap 
   B) = P(A) \times P(B|A)$
      \item Events $A$ and $B$ are \textbf{independent} if and only if $P(A \cap B) = 
    P(A)P(B)$ \\ and thus $P(A|B) = P(A)$ and $P(B|A) = P(B)$
  \end{itemize}
  
  \begin{tabular}{l l l}
      \textbf{Bayes' Theorem:} 
      & $P(A_i|B)$ &$= \frac{P(B|A_i)P(A_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)P(B|A_i)}$\\
      && $= \frac{P(B|A_i)P(A_i)}{P(B|A_1)P(A_1) + P(B|A_2)P(A_2)+ . . . + P(B|A_n)P(A_n)}$\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[my tcb box, title=Continuous Random Variables, sidebyside, sidebyside align=top, righthand width=4cm, lower separated=false]
  Sea $X$ una variable aleatoria \textbf{continua} \\
  
    \textbf{Funci\'on de Densidad} (pdf):\\ $P(a \leq X \leq b) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$
     \begin{enumerate}
     \setlength\itemsep{0em}
      \item $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$
      \item $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x) dx = 1$
    \end{enumerate}
  
    \textbf{Cumulative Distributive Function} (cdf):\\ $F(x) = P(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) dt$ \\
  
    \begin{tabular}{lp{8cm} l}
      Mediana: & $x$ tal que $F(x) = 0.5$ \\
      $Q_1$ y $Q_3$: & $x$ tal que $F(x) = 0.25$\\
       & y $x$ tal que $F(x) = 0.75$\\
      Media ($\mu$): & $E(X) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} xf(x) dx$ \\
      Valor esperado: & $E(g(X)) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} g(x)f(x) dx$ \\
      Varianza ($\sigma^2$): & $Var(X) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (x-\mu)^2f(x) dx$\\
  & \qquad\qquad$ = E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$\\
      D. T\'ipica ($\sigma$): & $DT(X) = \sqrt{Var(X)}$
  \end{tabular}
  
  \tcblower
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={100pt}, thick, scale=0.77, transform canvas={scale=0.77}, declare function={%
    normcdf(\x,\m,\s)=1/(1 + exp(-0.07056*((\x-\m)/\s)^3 - 1.5976*(\x-\m)/\s));
    gauss(\x,\u,\v)=1/(\v*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\u)^2)/(2*\v^2));
   }]
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2},
     xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=0,
     domain=-3:3,xlabel=$x$,axis lines=middle,axis on top]
      \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$\PDF(x)$,ytick=\empty,ymax=0.6]
      \addplot[smooth, black,thick,name path=gauss] {gauss(x,0,1)};     
      \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$\CDF(x)$,ymax=1.19]
      \addplot[smooth, black,thick] {normcdf(x,0,1)};
    \end{groupplot}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]